# WaitUntil IF Cond

Tags: .net, .net-core, async-await, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

I am using the paralel Foreach. Also I call the webapi in the foreach. I want to control response from the api. If I get the true or something value, I want to finish all tasks and foreach iteration.

I search in the stackoverflow but I can not see any response.

```
Task<bool>[] tasks = new Task<bool>[customers.Count()];
CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
CancellationToken token = tokenSource.Token;
ParallelOptions po = new ParallelOptions();
po.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = System.Environment.ProcessorCount;

Parallel.ForEach(customers, po, async (customer, state, index) =>
{
    po.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    var filePath = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "Photos", $"{customer.CustomerNumber}.jpg");
    byte[] secondImageBytes = await System.IO.File.ReadAllBytesAsync(filePath).ConfigureAwait(false);
    ByteArrayContent secondImage = new ByteArrayContent(secondImageBytes);

    var test = await SomeFunction().ConfigureAwait(false);
    if (test)
    {
        //cancel all foreach task
    }
});
```

For Understanding , test code :

```
  static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();
        List<TaskItem> taskList = new();
        taskList.Add(new TaskItem { Id = 1, Delay = 100, isOkey = true, Name = "Try 1" });
        taskList.Add(new TaskItem { Id = 2, Delay = 2000, isOkey = false, Name = "Try 2" });
        taskList.Add(new TaskItem { Id = 3, Delay = 100, isOkey = false, Name = "Try 3" });
        taskList.Add(new TaskItem { Id = 4, Delay = 100, isOkey = false, Name = "Try 4" });
        taskList.Add(new TaskItem { Id = 5, Delay = 100, isOkey = false, Name = "Try 5" });
        taskList.Add(new TaskItem { Id = 6, Delay = 200, isOkey = false , Name = "Try 6" });
        taskList.Add(new TaskItem { Id = 7, Delay = 10000, isOkey = false, Name = "Try 7" });
        taskList.Add(new TaskItem { Id = 8, Delay = 10000, isOkey = false, Name = "Try 8" });
        taskList.Add(new TaskItem { Id = 9, Delay = 10000, isOkey = false, Name = "Try 9" });
        var control=await TestTask2Async(taskList);
        Console.WriteLine("Result ="+control);
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    public static async Task<int> TestTaskAsync(List<TaskItem> taskList)
    {       
        var matchedId = 0;       
        try
        {
            var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var token = tokenSource.Token;
            var SomeTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
            {               
                await Task.WhenAll(taskList.AsEnumerable().Select(async item =>
                {
                    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                    await Task.Delay(100);
                    await Task.Delay(1000);
                    await Task.Delay(item.Delay);                        
                    Console.WriteLine("Process for " + item.Id);
                    if (item.isOkey)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Founded " + item.Id);
                        matchedId = item.Id;                            
                        tokenSource.Cancel();                            
                    }
                }));
            },token);
            await SomeTask.Result;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        return matchedId;
    }


    public static async Task<int> TestTask2Async(List<TaskItem> taskList)
    {
        var matchedId = 0;
        try
        {
            var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var token = tokenSource.Token;
            
            await Task.WhenAll(taskList.AsEnumerable().Select(async item =>
            {
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                await Task.Delay(100).ConfigureAwait(false); 
                await Task.Delay(1000).ConfigureAwait(false); 
                await Task.Delay(item.Delay).ConfigureAwait(false); 
                Console.WriteLine("Process for " + item.Id);
                if (item.isOkey)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Founded " + item.Id);
                    matchedId = item.Id;
                    tokenSource.Cancel();
                }
            }));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
        return matchedId;
    }
  public class TaskItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Delay { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool isOkey { get; set; }
}
```

- Result :

  Process for 4

  Process for 5

  Process for 1

  Process for 3

  Founded 1

  Process for 6

  Process for 2

  Process for 7

  Process for 9

  Process for 8

  Result =1

  11.2402357

But I want to if Founded (bla) , the all task will be die , I dont want to see Process for (bla) after Founded.

For this example I just want to see :

Process for 4

Process for 5

Process for 1

Process for 3

Founded 1

Result =1

1.2402357

Answer (score 1):

`Parallel.ForEach` was not designed to work with `async`-`await`.

That `Parallel.ForEach` will terminate as soon as the first non completed `await` is reached for all items.

Try this instead:

```
var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
var token = tokenSource.Token;

await Task.WhenAll(customers.Select(async customer =>
{
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    var filePath = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "Photos", $"{customer.CustomerNumber}.jpg");
    var secondImageBytes = await File.ReadAllBytesAsync(filePath).ConfigureAwait(false);
    var secondImage = new ByteArrayContent(secondImageBytes);

    var test = await SomeFunction().ConfigureAwait(false);
    if (test)
    {
        tokenSource.Cancel();
    }
}));
```

Also, don't use `Task.Factory.StartNew` with `async`-`await`. Use `Task.Run` instead.

One thing you need to know about cancellation tokens is that it signals the intention of cancellation, but it doesn't cancel anything by itself. The code needs to check it and cancel in whatever way needed.

Try this:

```
public static async Task<int> TestTask2Async(List<TaskItem> taskList)
{
    var matchedId = 0;
    try
    {
        var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var token = tokenSource.Token;

        await Task.WhenAll(taskList.AsEnumerable().Select(async item =>
        {
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            // add token to the call to Task.Delay
            await Task.Delay(100, token).ConfigureAwait(false);
            await Task.Delay(1000, token).ConfigureAwait(false);
            await Task.Delay(item.Delay, token).ConfigureAwait(false);
            // check it again
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            Console.WriteLine("Process for " + item.Id);
            if (item.isOkey)
            {
                // cancel as soon as the condition has been met
                tokenSource.Cancel();
                Console.WriteLine("Founded " + item.Id);
                matchedId = item.Id;
            }
        }));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
    return matchedId;
}
```

Comment: Can use List<Customer> in the WhenAll parameter ? Now I have a error already. Like this : Error CS1660 Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'IEnumerable<Task>' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: Thanks for your support. But in async function I can not use the File.ReadAllBytesAsync(filePath).ConfigureAwait(false); this method.
"ControllerBase.File(byte[], string)' is a method, which is not valid in the given context.".

Also If I writing "System.IO.File.ReadAllBytesAsync" , I got a error also.

Comment: I have a error like that : "System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()&#xD;&#xA;   at "

Comment: That's because the cancellation token was cancelled. Wasn't that what you wanted?

Comment: I added example code and want I want to result